# Как отсортировать объекты класса по нескольким полям одновременно?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

Как отсортировать объекты класса по нескольким полям одновременно в python3 ?
Подходят ли для этого lambda функции? Вот пример сортировки по одному полю.

```
 self.args = sorted(self.args, key=lambda x: x.attr1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [94]: data = [(3,4,5), (5,6,7), (3,3,9), (3,3,3)]
```

сортировка по всем полям:

```
In [95]: sorted(data)
Out[95]: [(3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 9), (3, 4, 5), (5, 6, 7)]
```

сортировка по первым двум полям:

```
In [96]: sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[:2])
Out[96]: [(3, 3, 9), (3, 3, 3), (3, 4, 5), (5, 6, 7)]
```

---

при работе со словарями или именованными атрибутами классов можно воспользоваться напрямую именами атрибутов или [operator.itemgetter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) / [operator.attrgetter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

data = [
    {'name': 'name_A', 'birthday': '1999-12-12', 'id': 1},
    {'name': 'name_B', 'birthday': '1965-11-11', 'id': 2},
    {'name': 'name_A', 'birthday': '1999-12-12', 'id': 3},
    {'name': 'name_A', 'birthday': '1970-01-01', 'id': 4},
    {'name': 'name_A', 'birthday': '2000-12-31', 'id': 5}
]    

In [108]: sorted(data, key=lambda x: (x['name'], x['birthday']))
Out[108]:
[{'name': 'name_A', 'birthday': '1970-01-01', 'id': 4},
 {'name': 'name_A', 'birthday': '1999-12-12', 'id': 1},
 {'name': 'name_A', 'birthday': '1999-12-12', 'id': 3},
 {'name': 'name_A', 'birthday': '2000-12-31', 'id': 5},
 {'name': 'name_B', 'birthday': '1965-11-11', 'id': 2}]

In [106]: sorted(data, key=lambda x: (itemgetter('name')(x), itemgetter('birthday')(x)))
Out[106]:
[{'name': 'name_A', 'birthday': '1970-01-01', 'id': 4},
 {'name': 'name_A', 'birthday': '1999-12-12', 'id': 1},
 {'name': 'name_A', 'birthday': '1999-12-12', 'id': 3},
 {'name': 'name_A', 'birthday': '2000-12-31', 'id': 5},
 {'name': 'name_B', 'birthday': '1965-11-11', 'id': 2}]
```

Comment: Уже разобрался. Второй Ваш пример помог мне в этом. Большое Вам спасибо